# Sorting correct scores to correct names (Parallel Arrays) C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

as mentioned above I am trying to display the correct scores to the correct users using parallel arrays where it should display the name of a student and their score if they got below 40.

Currently I have have done this but it does not allocate the score to the correct name.

Code:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //bool YesNo = Console.ReadKey;
        // Empty Variable arrays declared for usage.
        int[] classScores = new int[5];
        string[] studentNames = new string[5];
        object[] ClassANDStudent = new object[5];

        //
        //   if (YesNo == true)
        //Loop Method for user input for student name.
        for (int i = 0; i < studentNames.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a Student Name.");
            studentNames[i] = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter marks.");
            classScores[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        }
        //


        var Lessthan40Array = classScores.Where(OverallMark => OverallMark <= 40).ToArray();

        Array.Sort(studentNames, classScores, 0, studentNames.Length);
        Array.Sort(studentNames, Lessthan40Array, 0, Lessthan40Array.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < studentNames.Length; i++)
        {
            ClassANDStudent[i] = studentNames[i] + " " + classScores[i];
        }



        //
       for (int i = 0; i < Lessthan40Array.Length; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(studentNames[i] + " " + Lessthan40Array[i]);
          //  Console.WriteLine(" {0,-10}: {1}", studentNames[i], Lessthan40Array[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you are using parallel arrays instead of a simple class to store related data?

Comment: Its a part of using arrays in general, so I need to be able to do this I have learned a lot of it myself just cant sort it to the correlating fields. (basically a task given)

Comment: Are you required to sort, though? Or do you just need to display the data? (the title mentions sorting, but the description only mentions displaying students with scores < 40)

Comment: Just display them sorry.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < studentNames.Length; i++) if (classScores[i] < 40) Console.WriteLine("Student " + studentNames[i] + " only scored " + classScores[i]);`

Comment: Sure, depending on what you're storing in the dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the help pal, how do I mark you as correct haha just started to use this!

Comment: No problem. I will post it as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you really need to do is loop through all your scores and output the student information (from both arrays) for any index where the score is less than 40. The problem with your code above is that, as soon as you sort one of the arrays, they are not in sync anymore.

One of the first things I usually do when trying to get numbers from the user is create a helper method that will do some validation (using `int.TryParse`) to make sure they actually enter an integer. This method takes a string as a prompt to display to the user, and it keeps prompting them until they enter a valid number:

```
private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt)
{
    int input;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input));

    return input;
}
```

With that out of the way, here's the sample code that will prompt the user for how many students they want to enter, and then collects the name and score for each one into two separate arrays. Then it just uses a counter to loop through the scores array, and outputs the student name and score for any who scored less than 40:

```
private static void Main()
{
    int numStudents = GetIntFromUser("Enter the number of students: ");

    int[] scores = new int[numStudents];
    string[] names = new string[numStudents];

    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nStudent #" + (i + 1));
        Console.Write(" - Enter student's name: ");
        names[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        scores[i] = GetIntFromUser(" - Enter student's score: ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nHere are the students who scored less than 40:");

    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
    {
        if (scores[i] < 40)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" - " + names[i] + " scored " + scores[i]);
        }
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually sort before writing the scores:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] classScores = new int[]{30,50,25,39,62};
    string[] studentNames = new string[]{"Jim","John","Mary","Peter","Sarah"};
        Array.Sort(classScores, studentNames);   // sort both according to scores
    for (int i = 0; i < classScores.Length; i++)
    {
        if (classScores[i] < 40)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(classScores[i] + " " + studentNames[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

If you have more than 2 arrays, create an array of indexes 0 to length-1:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] classScores = new int[]{30,50,25,39,62};
    string[] firstNames = new string[]{"Jim","John","Mary","Peter","Sarah"};
    string[] lastNames = new string[]{"Thorpe","Smith","Jones","Tork","Conner"};
    int[] index = new int[]{0,1,2,3,4};
        Array.Sort(classScores, index);   // sort both according to scores
    for (int i = 0; i < classScores.Length; i++)
    {
        if (classScores[i] < 40)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(classScores[i] + " " +
                firstNames[index[i]] + " " + lastNames[index[i]]);
        }
    }
}
```